# "in the summer" or "in summer"

Tags: articles

Both are correct forms when we talk about seasons of the year from what I learnt. But is there any difference between "in summer" and "in the summer"? The answer is no.  They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 12):

There may be, depending on the context. *In summer* refers to the season in general. *In the summer* may also do so, but it can also refer to a particular summer.

Comment: Thank you. Are they equally common when used in general?

Comment: It’s hard to know for sure. Both the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the British National Corpus have more than twice as many records for _in the summer_ as they have for _in summer_.  That may simply be because people refer to a particular summer more often than they do to summer in general.

Comment: Which one do you prefer to use? Which form do you think you hear more often? (used in general meaning of course). I remember once an American teacher corrected my "in summer" for "in the summer" but then apologized and said that "in summer" had been correct. I think that is an indication that at least Americans usually say it  with "the". Or is it?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it depends on the context.

Comment: I meant summer in general.

Comment: Context again. I can say no more than that.

Comment: But I do believe that Americans have a particular way of talking about *the summer* which is unique to them. It doesn't so much refer to summer as a season, as it does to a particular time period when people are home from college, and life is observing a different tempo e.g. *He worked for a homeless charity over the summer*. In Britain we tend not to use *summer* in that sense, but might say *He worked for a homeless charity during the vacation*.